# how to set subreport Name through C# code?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, c#-2.0

I need to set the subreport name through code. How do i do this ?
i dont want to change through Format Editor.
Is there any way to set the Sub report name in C# ?

For Ex:

int number ="10";
I need this number to be shown as subreport name.and when clicked on that number,subreport details will be shown.

```
Name        Address   Number
Mercury     London   **10**
```

Here number 10 is on demand-subreport.

How to set subreport name in C# code ?

Comment: Missing a whole lot of information.  Please try to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ReportDocument.Subreports().Name property.